# Getting Nrf24l01 modules to work!

Tags: nrf24l01+

I am at my wit's end with these Nrf24l01s. A bit of history: I have ordered about 25 of these, tried the adapter board, read every article, tried every sketch (including Robin's tutorial), powered the modules with a separate power supply.

Has anyone else had these issues? Is there anything anyone has discovered on getting these to work? I am 12 years old and am trying to use these for a science project. Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Tnx,
Ricky

**edit:**
I went back to just the simplest "hello world" sketch and I can't even get this to work: nothing received in serial monitor (I did notice the Tx LED is lit in the receiver, is this correct?) Sorry if I posted this wrong.

```cpp
//Include Libraries
#include <SPI.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>

//create an RF24 object
RF24 radio(9, 8);  // CE, CSN

//address through which two modules communicate.
const byte address[6] = "00001";

void setup()
{
  radio.begin();
  
  //set the address
  radio.openWritingPipe(address);
  
  //Set module as transmitter
  radio.stopListening();
}

void loop()
{
  //Send message to receiver
  const char text[] = "Hello World";
  radio.write(&text, sizeof(text));
  
  delay(1000);
}
```

Receiver:

```cpp
//Include Libraries
#include <SPI.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>

//create an RF24 object
RF24 radio(9, 8);  // CE, CSN

//address through which two modules communicate.
const byte address[6] = "00001";

void setup()
{
  while (!Serial);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  
  radio.begin();
  
  //set the address
  radio.openReadingPipe(0, address);
  
  //Set module as receiver
  radio.startListening();
}

void loop()
{
  //Read the data if available in buffer
  if (radio.available())
  {
    char text[32] = {0};
    radio.read(&text, sizeof(text));
    Serial.println(text);
  }
}
```

Comment: `Has anyone else had these issues?` ... you did not describe any issues  .... `Is there anything anyone has discovered on getting those to work?` ... many people use them, so `yes`

Comment: please describe what you are doing with the modules and describe how your attempts fail .... and, please ask specific questions that do not have a simple `yes/no` answer

Comment: I am building a remote temperature/ humidity sensor. I am using 2 Arduino unos, dht22 sensor and of course the nrf24l01.  On the transmitter uno I can open up the serial monitor and see that the temp/ humidity is being displayed correctly so that part is working.  I am using the dht22 sensor libarary and the Tmrh24 libarary as recommended.  I seem at times to get some Random characters.  It seems when I touch the uno the board led tx does flash and acts differently when I hold the uno in my hand vs not. I am using male to female etc wires for connecting. I have also tryed the nrf24l01+ w ant 2

Comment: temperature and humidity values are irrelevant to the communication problem ... reduce your code to transmit and to receive only a single character .... remove the dht22 sensor ... get communication working first ... add the temperature code after .... add the wiring diagram, code and a description of any errors to your post at top of this page.

Comment: Posted in answer

Comment: Move the modules further apart, or change the power output in code (`radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MIN)`).

Comment: Try using one of the TMRh20's library's examples and get communication working there first.

Comment: Thanks to all who commented and provided advise. I did go to TMRH20 examples I tryed the simple transmit receive node sketch